# How can I rewrite a URL only if the page doesn't exist?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a web page at `myWebsite.com` and in the same directory a small number of other pages like `myWebsite.com/about` and `myWebsite.com/contact`.

I'm trying to make a user-profile system where if I go to `myWebsite.com/user1` it redirects to the index but can use `user1` as a variable (to pull their user account information from the database).

How can I do this only if the extension to the URL is not a page that actually exists?

Edit:

...Without hard-coding in the pages that do exist like `/about` and `/contact`

Comment: why not only rewrite the urls you are going to use?

Comment: @rtfm The system will contain any number of users so I can't Rewrite rules whenever new user Registers

Comment: nooooooooooo you dont write a rule per user, but you will have a ruler for /about, /contact

Comment: ie `RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ about.php?user_id=$1 [NC]`

Comment: Ideally, if I could, I'd do neither

Comment: well I'm lost..

Comment: Why not let the URL hierarchy help you:  `mywebsite.com/user/1`  That way it's only  one rewrite rule.

Comment: I could, @TimMorton - and I know it's what things like stackoverflow, reddit, and facebook do but twitter manages to have a setup where they have both `twitter.com/[username]` and `twitter/about`

Comment: I would look at it from a different angle:  instead of selectively rewriting, send *everything* through `index.php`.  If your site has all pages in the database, then it's just a matter of matching the [slug].

Answer (score 1):

If your system uses physical files or directories for `/about` and `/contact` then you could use this common instruction to rewrite *those that do not* to `index.php`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This simply checks if the requested page

- **IS NOT** `index.php`
- **IS NOT** an existing file
- **IS NOT** an existing directory

then rewrite to `index.php`. Afterwards, you will be able to access `/user1`  via `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']`  in your `index.php` file.

That said I agree with the comments that sending *everything* through index.php would be best, and the above snippet could get you going in that direction as well.